# Unable to install packages using chef

Tags: windows, chef-infra

```
Error executing action `install` on resource 'windows_package[autologon]'
           ================================================================================

           Chef::Exceptions::CannotDetermineWindowsInstallerType
           -----------------------------------------------------
           Installer type for Windows Package 'autologon' not specified and cannot be determined from file extension 'exe'

           Resource Declaration:
           ---------------------
           # In C:/Users/kitchen/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/rclient/recipes/windows.rb

            26: windows_package 'autologon' do
            27:   source "#{node['rclient']['remote_root_url']}/autologon/3.10/Autologon.exe"
            28: end
            29:
```

Also same issue for IEDriverServer.exe and msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe packages.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_package.html for information. You almost certainly need to specify `:installer_type`.

https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/package/windows.rb#L91 is the method where the error you see is being produced.